# VS 2008/2010 Installation problem

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010, installation

This is my problem:

When I get to the license terms the installation window "dies". I mean, looks like it's working a lot (renderizing the objects of the window, showing the loading cursor), and it would be normal if my pc were old, but I do not.

The strangest part is when I check the task manager. It shows an invisible line at 25% of cpu resource usage for the installation program, and even when the proc has nothing else to do, this percentage doesn't grow. What keeps on growing is the RAM usage.

I've tried to give Realtime priority to the process without generating any changes to it (still @25%).

What bothers me is that my atom netbook can install both VSs without any further problems, but my far more efficient PC can't.

**My PC Specs**

- Processor: Intel Core i5 x64
- OS: Win7 Professional x64
- RAM: 6gb

Is the OS the problem? Is it Visual Studio?

---

Thanks for your answers, even workarounds will be well received at this instance.

*To add to this I have to say that vs2005 is actually installed in the troubled PC and works perfectly.*

Comment: aint this a serverfault question?

Comment: There is no x64 version of visual studio.

Comment: @yetanodercoder: It could be, but, I thought devs here would encounter the problem (and solution) quicker and more useful than there, since a lot of them use this programs periodically.

Comment: @Hans Passant: great, but I know people who is currently using VS2010 @x64 machines and they are very happy (_it works for them_). So, even if there are no x64 versions (thanks for correcting me there) It has to be some issue somewhere.

Comment: From [ServerFault - Visual Studio x86 on an x64 machine](http://serverfault.com/questions/213902/can-i-install-visual-studio-2010-professional-x86-on-an-x64-machine) there should be no problem... but there is!